# I dug holes for my pergola too wide

Tags: hole, pergola

I accidentally dug holes for my posts way too wide. They're like 22 inches wide and the width of the post is just 3 inches. I didn't know at the time that you only need the width of the hole to be just 4 times the width of the post. Anything more is just wasting cement. Question is, how do i make the holes narrower to the right width and at the same time keeping a perfect square shape to the hole?
Note: the posts are already attached to the roof and are sitting in the 2 foot holes so taking them out is out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Not to big of a concern.

You could take a 12" [sono tube](https://www.lowes.com/pd/QUIKRETE-Common-12-in-Actual-11-5-in-QUIK-TUBE-48-in-Concrete-Tube-Form/3005464), slice it length wise and then pull it open enough to get it around the post. Then just overlap the slice and glue it with outdoor construction adhesive.

Once the glue sets you can back fill around the outside of the tube with soil, *keeping it plumb and straight*, and then you are ready to fill with concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to put a 1 foot square patio block in the hole for the pole to rest on, then fill the hole with road crush (3/4 on down crushed limestone or sandstone) Tamp hard every 4" of fill.

If you just need short pilings, a 5 gallon bucket makes a satisfactory mould for concrete.

I did the following here on clay soil:

- Augered a 2 foot deep hole in the ground with a 16" auger.
- Put road crush in the bottom of the hole and packed. Did that up to about 4" from the surface.
- Set a 5 gallon bucket that I cut the bottom off upside down on the gravel.  Adjusted gravel until top (really bottoms) were level.
- Filled each bucket with more road crush, packing with shovel handle and sledge, since my tamper wouldn't fit.
- Placed a pyramid deck block on each one.
- Put 2x4' on edge between the deck blocks.  (They ahve slots for this.)
- Laid 6.5 foot square pallets on the 2x4's.  These were very heavy pallets used to ship truck tires.  Both faces were 2x8 fir with only 1" between boards.  I later filled in the gaps with strips of 2x4.

Net result: 12 x 24' deck for the price of a few 2x4's a few pyramid blocks, and scrounge.

In the ensuing 6 years it hasn't heaved at all.

Gotchas:  Use black pails.  The ones that motor oil come in work well.  They ahve lots of UV inhibitor so they don't get brittle from sunlight exposure.

Comment: I have clay soil and since clay soil has the ability to retain water, gravel would pull that water into itself and create a puddle all around or atleast that's what I've read.

Comment: Not if you mound up.  See edit.